# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

Tags: python, flask

I always get this **error message** in Python **if I reload my page**. **Before I refresh the page, my code works**. Here is the error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'my_data' is undefined
```

and here is the line that is causing the error in html:

```
<h2>{{ my_data[10] }}</h2>
```

Here is my code in py:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']

        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis =1)
        my_data = []
        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            column_edit = column_edit * 5
            my_data.append(column_edit)
            

     return render_template('index.html', my_data = my_data)
```

If I print only `<h2>{{ my_data }}</h2>` , there is no error. However, I would like to access the individual values ​​in the list.

Comment: It looks like `my_data` will only be defined for a POST request. How about for a GET request?

Comment: @Gino Mempin Even if I add 'GET' it still doesn't work

Comment: Because even if you add GET to `methods=[...]`, inside the `index` function, `my_data` will not be defined for a GET request (which is what happens when you "reload the page"). Try this, print `my_data` before the `return` line. It *should* be defined before you pass it to your template.

Comment: No, it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Declare my_data outside the if condition.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    my_data = []  # get data from database
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_data = []
        inpt = request.form['inpt']
        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis=1)
        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            column_edit = column_edit * 5
            my_data.append(column_edit)
        # save my_data to a database
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', my_data = my_data)
```

Comment: Try to add `print(my_data)` above `return render_template('index.html', my_data = my_data)` to see if your list have items.

Comment: okay, your my_data should be outside the if condition.

Comment: If i put my_data out of the if condition i still get this error message. And also if i print my_data before the return

Comment: Just redirect after you submit POST. You might also need to add a database for this. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior

Comment: The list my_data contains elements, because if I just print {{my_data}}, the complete list is output and it works fine. But when I print {{my_data [10]}} I get an error

Comment: What you need is a dynamic page rendering that requires an in-memory database like Redis or an ordinary database MySQL.

Comment: It is still not working. (
your suggestion above) 
Can I use my_data from this function in another def function?
So that I can iterate through the list in a new Def function and then output the values ​​in html?

Comment: If i call this return it also worked well. `return render_template('index.html', my_data = my_data[10])`

Answer (score 0):

Without the POST request, `my_data` is an empty array and `my_data[10]` doesn't exists.

Comment: But if i only {{my_data}} it prints my whole list. So my list isnt empty.

Comment: If you reload the page, also the whole list should be empty or undefined. You define `my_data` only on a POST request and if you reload the page without POST data, `my_data` is undefined.

Comment: Ah that could be possible. But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Implement a behaviour in case of a GET request or invalid submitted data that fills your my_data array with default data.